# Log-in screen - overlay

Tags: html, css

I've redesigning a web page and want to get rid of the login form in the header. I want to replace it with a 'login' button that, when clicked, will display a login form in an overlay on the page.

The effect I'm after is similar to what is on this site http://www.teamtalk.com/ (see top corner). Is this tricky to implement? How would I achieve such an effect?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using jQuery you might want to check out [jQuery Modal Dialog](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/modaldialog) At any rate you want to look into model dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

I just whipped this together. Should be enough to understand how to implement.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login popup</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function closeLogin() {
            document.getElementById("container").removeChild(document.getElementById("overlay"));
        }
        function loginOverlay () {
            var overlay = document.createElement("div");
            var loginForm = document.createElement("div");
            overlay.setAttribute("id", "overlay");
            overlay.style.position = "fixed";
            overlay.style.top = "0px";
            overlay.style.left = "0px";
            overlay.style.right = "0px";
            overlay.style.bottom = "0px";
            overlay.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(82,255,53,0.56)";
            loginForm.style.width = "500px";
            loginForm.style.marginTop = "100px";
            loginForm.style.marginLeft = "auto";
            loginForm.style.marginRight = "auto";
            loginForm.innerHTML = "<form> First name: <input type=\"text\" name=\"firstname\"/> <br/>Lastname: <input type=\"text\" name=\"lastname\"/></form><br/><a href='#c' onclick='closeLogin();'>close</a> ";
            overlay.appendChild(loginForm);
            document.getElementById("container").appendChild(overlay);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"><a href="#" onclick="loginOverlay()">Login</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```